# how to generate crystal reports in mvc 4 using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have to generate report using stored procedure with passing two input values to the procedure. in mvc 4,How can I achieve this?

Comment: It depends on your provider. Do you use Entity Framework or ADO.NET? EF 6.0 provides support for stored procedures. However in other versions of EF is available yourDbContext.Database.SqlQuery() and you can fetch your results to List.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework. How Cal I achieve? Please provide how to  call report from controller and pass EmpID,Date to procedure @MiroslavHolec